# phone stuck in recovery and blank screen

Tags: adb, rom-flashing, recovery-mode, twrp, flashtool

so i have a condor plume L1 the the default rom was full of bloatware every 30 sec i get an add so i used adb to install twrp and wanted to install a custom rom but i had a problem with */data couldnt mount* and stuck with that problems for days after that i decided to flash it and install the original rom using SP flash too everything looked fine but after its done andi unpluged the phone i got a blank screen when i press Power + vol up botton i get a menu

```
- recovery
- fastboot 
- normal`
```

and when i go to any option its just blank screen adb no longer recognize my phone but sp flash tool recognize my phone when i choose fastboot

Comment: Was your phone encrypted? If it was, use fastboot to erase data with fastboot erase data and, if the problem is encryption, you'll be fine.

Comment: erasing data mean i'll lose the rom i have on the phone memory but i'll try it

Comment: You won't lose the ROM, only the user data. The ROM is found in the system partition, unless you are referring to the ROM zip file.

Comment: i used an earlier version of twrp and that fixed the problem for me but now i'm getting error 255 every time i try to install the new rom zip file from the phone internal  memory